# AJAX Return Whole Page in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i try to use ajax method with jquairy in wordpress to check a return from a specific function in php file but it return the whole page with aloto of s i only want the resulted paragraph
"i am new with ajax"

AJAX

```
<div class="result"></div>
        <h1><button class="next">Next Round</button></h1>
        <script>
            $('.next').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wmyc-ajax/",
                    success: function (result,status,xhr) {
                        $(".result").empty();
                        $(".result").append(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

PHP file

```
 <?php
    session_name('WMYC');
    session_start();
    function checkRound($round){
        global $wpdb;
        $table_teams = $wpdb->prefix . 'teams';
        $check = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM $table_teams where xy='$round' AND trainer = {$_SESSION['trainer']}");
        if($checkrows != NULL) {
            $_SESSION['round']++;
            echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0">';
        } else {
            echo '<p id="parag">Please Wait...!</p>';
        }
    }
checkRound('r'.$_SESSION['round']);
?>
```

it return the whole page not only the result i am looking for so how can i get the result of the PHP function whither its the refresh page or the 'Please Wait...!' paragraph?

Comment: Remove all the other content from the page, or call `exit()` at the end of your function to prevent further processing. Also note that refreshing the page after making an AJAX request is almost entirely pointless, as it makes the purpose of the AJAX request moot.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i added it to blank template but still there are some divs with classes that add padding and margin add white space around the the result